# Python - Problems with zipfiles

Tags: python, file, for-loop, zip

my zip file (folder) with 20 text files in it is saved locally. I have the directory of that.
What I want to do:

1. I want to upzip the folder, search through with a loop, to get the right text file (for ex. "testcase1"), which should be edited.
2. Open this text file and add new line for example "hello world" -> save and close
3. Next I want do zip this folder again and save it locally in a special directory
4. return the path of the new zip file (folder)

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. If you're having trouble opening, reading and writing files, please share the code you've tried. If the Zip-related functions are working, please remove those from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
 import zipfile
            def update_log(self, input_dir, output_dir):
            '''
            function to update the log files
            '''
    
            with ZipFile(input_dir, 'r') as zip:
                # printing all the contents of the zip file
                zip.printdir()
                # extracting all the files
                self.logger.info("Extracting all the files now...")
                os.chdir(output_dir)
                zip.extractall()
                print('Done!')

            #for loop, opening file, edit and close
            for key in testcase_dict:
                log_file = open('{}.txt'.format(key), 'a')
                log_file.write('hello world')
                log_file.close()

            # calling function to get all file paths in the directory
            file_paths = self.get_all_file_paths()
            # printing the list of all files to be zipped
            for file_name in file_paths:
                print(file_name)
                # writing files to a zipfile
            with ZipFile('log-test.zip', 'w') as zip:
                # writing each file one by one
                for file in file_paths:
                    zip.write(file)
    
            print("All files zipped successfully")
            return None
    
    
        def get_all_file_paths(self):
            # initializing empty file paths list
            file_paths = []
    
            # crawling through directory and subdirectories
            for root, directories, files in os.walk("home/test"):
                for filename in files:
                    # join the two strings in order to form the full filepath.
                    filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
                    file_paths.append(filepath)
    
                    # returning all file paths
            self.logger.info(file_paths)
            return file_paths
```